# scikit-learn return value of LogisticRegression.predict_proba

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, probability, logistic-regression

What exactly does the `LogisticRegression.predict_proba` function return?

In my example I get a result like this:

```py
array([
    [4.65761066e-03, 9.95342389e-01],
    [9.75851270e-01, 2.41487300e-02],
    [9.99983374e-01, 1.66258341e-05]
])
```

From other calculations, using the sigmoid function, I know, that the second column is the probabilities. The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba) says that the first column is `n_samples`, but that can't be, because my samples are reviews, which are texts and not numbers. The documentation also says that the second column is `n_classes`. That certainly can't be, since I only have two classes (namely, `+1` and `-1`) and the function is supposed to be about calculating probabilities of samples really being of a class, but not the classes themselves.

What is the first column really and why it is there?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
4.65761066e-03 + 9.95342389e-01 = 1
9.75851270e-01 + 2.41487300e-02 = 1
9.99983374e-01 + 1.66258341e-05 = 1
```

The first column is the probability that the entry has the `-1` label and the second column is the probability that the entry has the `+1` label. Note that classes are ordered as they are in self.classes_.

If you would like to get the predicted probabilities for the positive label only, you can use `logistic_model.predict_proba(data)[:,1]`. This will yield you the `[9.95342389e-01, 2.41487300e-02, 1.66258341e-05]` result.

Answer (score 1):

As [iulian explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36681493/19123103), each row of `predict_proba()`'s result is the probabilities that the observation in that row is of each class (and the classes are ordered as they are in `lr.classes_`).

In fact, it's also intimately tied to `predict()` in that each row's highest probability class is chosen by `predict()`. So for any `LogisticRegression` (or any classifier really), the following is True.

```py
lr = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)
highest_probability_classes = lr.predict_proba(X).argmax(axis=1)
all(lr.predict(X) == lr.classes_[highest_probability_classes])     # True
```