# What is predict_proba and [:,1] after (X_test) in code?

Tags: python, roc

I am doing logistic regression for titanic dataset. I could not understand [:, 1] in
code to create roc curve.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
logit_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, logmodel.predict(X_test))
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, logmodel.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='Logistic Regression (area = %0.2f)' % logit_roc_auc)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Survived or Not')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.savefig('Log_ROC')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Predicts the probability of the passenger being a survivor or not.

Answer (score 1):

Based on sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba), `predict_proba` returns probability estimates for all classes and the results are ordered by the label of classes.

Logistic regression is a binary classifier. Hence, `logmodel.predict_proba(X_test)` returns 2 columns for the negative and positive class. An example from [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681449/scikit-learn-return-value-of-logisticregression-predict-proba)

```
[[  4.65761066e-03   9.95342389e-01]
 [  9.75851270e-01   2.41487300e-02]
 [  9.99983374e-01   1.66258341e-05]]
```

Running `logmodel.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]` get the predicted probabilities of the positive label only, which yield `[9.95342389e-01, 2.41487300e-02, 1.66258341e-05]` in this example.

Comment: Thank you so much, now [:, 1] is clear to me.